# How to get a sharepoint file downloading link

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have Excel & csv files in a private sharepoint and needed to load them in ssis.

So, I need to have a link that will download files.

As example here is the shape for an .xlsx file

https://companyname.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/sharepointname/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B30ABDB69-3971-4866-B0B4-3002C8F85A80%7D&file=SRM%20Report%20-%20Unformated.xlsx&action=default&mobileredirect=true

if I click on share the link is :

https://companyname.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/sharepointname/EWnbqzBxOWZIsLQwAsj4WoABKL22OnlVJ_j7r_X1K4g1LQ?e=7q7Em9

I've tried :

https://companyname.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/sharepointname/EWnbqzBxOWZIsLQwAsj4WoABKL22OnlVJ_j7r_X1K4g1LQ?download=1

Its works . But when the Excel file is updated the link in ssis doesn't work anymore.

I would have some think like this :

https://companyname.sharepoint.com/prj/sharepointname/_layouts/15/download.aspx?e=....

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To get a document link to any file, you can follow the below steps.

This path will never change and it is path to document...

1. select any document
2. click on I icon on property pane
3. Scroll down to find the property called Path,
4. Use the icon to copy the path

You will path like below

https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/MyTec/Shared%20Documents/file-sample_100kB%20-%20Copy%20(6).doc

[image]

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, it is not currently supported to create a link which users can download files directly using this link without updating in SharePoint.